# Nexus 4 charging/uncharging while plugged in

Tags: battery, nexus-4, charging

I have a problem when charging my Nexus 4, I tried looking around to no avail.

My problem is that when I have my phone plugged in to charger it doesn't charge, Instead it flickers between charging and not charging really fast.

When I look at the battery icon in the top right, the lightning bolt is also flickering, indicating that the phone is switching between charging/discharging at high speeds.

My phone is dead right now and I can't charge it because when it is in this state, the net result is discharging (when it is plugged in that is).

I tried using my roommate's charger, and it sometimes works and sometimes does the same as my charger, also my device has the latest system update that happened (can't remember what number), but the problem has been happening way before then.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a hardware problem. Check your connection, if not power circuit...

Answer (score 0):

Its problem in cable. I have faced this issue. Try changing the cable.

Answer (score 0):

This is indicative of two possible issues.

- Your charger or charger's cable is failing
- Your phone's charging port is failing

I'd try using a varied assortment of different cables to charge it - the easiest and cheapest solution is to find a different cable that works. If that doesn't work, you might need to fix the charging port on the phone, which is obviously not an easy task.
You can also try using a wireless charger to charge it - that bypasses the bad cable connection completely.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the original charger or plugging your Nexus into a laptop via usb